# Standard small header size

Tags: pcb, header

Currently, I'm using standard headers with a pitch of 2.54mm (0.1"). These are quite big on my boards. Are there any surface mount standard headers, say in 0.05"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Samtec has a pretty wide range of small headers. 0.050" pitch is a standard size. They probably go smaller as well.

A few examples:

- [male headers](http://samtec.com/ProductInformation/TechnicalSpecifications/Overview.aspx?series=FTS)
- [surface mount sockets](http://samtec.com/ProductInformation/TechnicalSpecifications/Overview.aspx?series=FLE)

Comment: If anyone knows of a cheap supply of 10 way ribbon cables with 2x5 female headers in this size, please say

Comment: @Joby Taffey, I'd be interested too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really small board-board and board-cable connectors (down to 0.4 mm pitch), have a look at Hirose.

Answer (score 1):

2mm pitch is the next 'standard' down from 2.54.  And though it *sounds* like it's not that much smaller, it really is.

You may find that 0.05" (1.25-ish mm) is really *too* small for a lot of stuff, particularly prototype/low volume.

Answer (score 1):

0.100" headers come in SMT versions which can save a great deal of space while still being easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Global Connector Technology (GCT) offers a range of small and inexpensive vertical SMT headers, either [in 2.00mm (.079")](http://www.gct.co/pcb-board-to-board/header-socket-products.aspx?Pitch=2.00mm&MountType=Surface%20mount&Gender=Header&Orientation=Straight&) or [1.27mm (.050")](http://www.gct.co/pcb-board-to-board/header-socket-products.aspx?Pitch=1.27mm&Gender=Header&MountType=Surface%20mount&Orientation=Straight&).

They should be stocked by Newark (and Farnell/Element 14) in 2-10 positions, click the distribution links from the GCT pages (look for the green tick) to navigate to the exact range.  If you can't find what you seek MOQ's are circa  1,000+ to deal direct/vis distribution.

Actually 1.27mm (.050") connectors are superseding 2.00mm (.079") in volume sales, not by much, but they shade it.  Anyway, it's horses for courses so pick whichever ones you like.

GCT also product economical 1.00mm (.039") straight SMT headers which are freely available from Newark/Farnell in 2-10 positions.